# Updating a nullable DateTime field as null results in default DateTime value (0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, sql-server-express

I'm using ASP.NET Boilerplate MVC (not Core) template in my project, which uses EF6 as ORM. Database is SQL Server Express.

Here's my entity object (ignoring non-related properties):

```
public class Asset : AggregateRoot<long>
{
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? LastControlTime { get; set; }
}
```

When I create a new Asset, this field appropriately created as NULL. So, everything works as intented at first. But when I try to update an object with a simple service call, it screws up.

Here's the method in the application service class:

```
public void ResetLastControlTime (EntityDto<long> input)
{
    var asset = Repository.Get(input.Id);
    asset.LastControlTime = default(DateTime?);
}
```

This should reset that field to null. I also tried `asset.LastControlTime = null;`. But in the end  it's written "0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000" to that field in the database. I have lots of places in code that I control for a null value so now I had to change tons of old files or I must find some way to reset that field to simply NULL.

I checked similar questions here but cannot find an answer. All of them tells about nullable DateTime, which I already have. In SQL server table schema, Data Type is `datetime2(7)`, so I guess that's correct too. Oh and deleting the DataType annotation also didn't change anything.

So what am I missing here? What should I check to find the issue?

Comment: The date is converted to it's minvalue, perhaps because in that situation, the datetime cannot be null. Perhaps in that case, try to check on `DateTime.MinValue` instead?

Comment: All of your code and domain models look to be Nullable, and I havent' tried it, but I guess that default(DateTime?) is null while it's in memory. I can only imagine that you didn't let Entity Framework create your database schema, if that is the case, then perhaps the SQL field is set to NOT NULL? Nulls would certainly be removed if the SQL schema can't accept them. If you did get EF to craete the schema. If you added Nullable later on, you may need Add-Migration & Update-Database

Comment: Have you tried debugging and stepping through the code line by line and watching the value of `LastControlTime`? If you can establish the value of this at each point as you step through the code, you should be able to isolate the exact place where the behaviour is not as intended. From what I can see there is nothing in the code you have posted that would cause this behaviour, but there is nothing in the code you have posted that actually deals with saving the asset to the database, so the issue might be elsewhere in the process.

Comment: @MarkRabjohn My database is created with Code First approach, so it should be EF created. Though I have this line added for a reason I don't remember in `OnModelCreating` method: `modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));` I don't know if this would be related to the issue. By the way, I know the field is nullable because as I said, when creating a new Asset object, the datetime value begins at NULL.

Comment: @GarethD Well, the saving part is handled by the ABP's Unit of Work structure, afaik. It applies the changes made in C# objects to the database automatically after an application service method completes. Though I guess I could find a way to see the exact SQL command it sends to the server. I may catch something there (though I'm not sure how can I alter it).

Comment: I would usually use SQL Server Manager and do a 'Script As... CREATE TO' to view the schema as a create statement - if the code for the column has NOT NULL next to it, then your schema is wrong. You could also view the table in edit mode and try and set the field to NULL (CTRL+0), if it's not nullable it won't let you. I was reading https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-property-mappings-using-fluent-api.aspx looks like a column needs IsOptional(), so perhaps you need c.HasColumnType("datetime2").IsOptional()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose if all else fails, you can simplify most of your code by re-implementing the property:

```
public class Asset : AggregateRoot<long>
{
    public DateTime? _LastControlTime;
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? LastControlTime { 
      get {
        return _LastControlTime;
      }
      set {
        if (value == DateTime.MinValue) {
          _LastControlTime = null;
        } else {
          _LastControlTime = value;
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't really cut to the heart of the problem, but will let you progress without having to change all of your == null and .HasValue throughout the entire program.

Comment: It worked! So it seems the problem lies somewhere between the Repository and ORM boilerplate code, converting null value to minimum datetime. I don't know what it is but I'm too busy to care right now. So, thank you very much for this simple solution.